# Series of animations with tween class

Tags: flash, class, actionscript-2, tween

It seems that my actionscript2 is little rusty.
Problem:
I have to use tween class, to make bounce effect on 4 objects (before i slide them down off of the screen;small flash banner is in question), like this:

```
 var bob_up1:Tween = new Tween (Object(this).seat4,"_y",Bounce.easeInOut,-17,-22,1,true);
var bob_up2:Tween= new Tween (Object(this).seat3,"_y",Bounce.easeInOut,-17,-22,1,true);
```

...

I wouldn't like that these animations are played simultaneously. I would like to start second animation when the first one is  at the half (500ms), same with third object/animation(when second object hits certain point - at 500ms, start third), same with fourth...
So, my question is how to separate these 4 animations, what i could use as 'trigger' for animation start... I've tried with setInterval - no success...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking into [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), which offers a delay property for each tween. It seems to me that would suffice for your use case. If not, you could also look into [TimelineLite](http://www.greensock.com/timelinelite/) for sequencing tweens.

Comment: Yes, thanks, i've solved it with TweenMax - it has great delay() feature. That was all i need. :)